# How to remove \ when extract words by python?

Tags: python, text-extraction

I want to implement a function **`extract_words()`** that takes in a string of text as its single parameter and *returns* a `list` of the words in that string, like this:

input: `"There're six words in this string."`
output: `["There're", 'six', 'words', 'in', 'this', 'string']`

But when I write it like the following and run it in Jupyter Notebook, it shows like this:

[image]

I learned how to write this function by the following, so I tried this in Jupyter, and it shows correct:

[image]

So may I ask what's wrong with my code, and how to fix it?

Comment: 1) Please show code an output as text, not images, 2) If you want to **return a list**, then why are you using `str()`?

Comment: Please don't paste screen grab images of code. Copy and paste the text directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the cast to `str` inside your function. Just do `return inputStr.split()` and should works.

```
def __extract_words__(inputStr):
  return inputStr.split()

inputStr = "There're six words in this string."

__extract_words__(inputStr)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to replace. Those are escape characters because you returned a string

You want to return the split list as an actual list, not a `str()` - `return inputStr.split()`

Look at the docs for the `typing` module so the type checker would have shown you the issue more clearly. I.e. your function was actually returning a string.

---

I think what is confusing you is that you needed to use `str()` when you print the result, but that could be fixed like this

```
print(f'The list of words is {res}')
```

That being said, you don't really need your own function if the goal is to only print

```
test_string = input('text> ')
print(f'The list of words is {test_string.split()}')
```

Also, the `__function_name__` syntax (surrounding underscores) should be reserved for "magic functions" rather than user functions